# Azure event hub shared access signature reuse

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

i want to send messages to azure event hub with device which are not able to generate SAS token or key but are able to do HTTP get/post. so can we use device like raspberry pi to generate SAS key and can it be reused by the other device or even web applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any app that has the SAS token can call to the Event Hub to send/receive data for as long as that token does not expire. The only thing the Event Hub checks is that the signature is valid, and that the token is still valid, and has the permissions to do what you are doing. It does not care where it came from. The expiry time is set when you generate the key, so you will have to renew it.